# Circle class definition compiling with static error

Tags: class, static, geometry

I followed step by step with how we did this in class, yet when I try to compile I get the follow error:

error: non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context.

The line under questioning is
    cir1 = new Circle();
and 
    cir2 = new Circle();

I understand what the error means I am just having difficulty seeing what my mistake was because it is the exact same as what we did in class (or so I thought..)

```
 public class CircleDemo{
   public static void main(String[] args){
      Circle cir1, cir2;
      cir1 = new Circle();
      cir2 = new Circle();
      cir1.setRadius(3.0);
      cir2.setRadius(11.01);
      System.out.println("Area of the first circle: " + cir1.findArea());
       System.out.println("Circumference of the first circle: " + cir1.findCircumference());
       System.out.println("Area of the second circle: " + cir2.findArea());
       System.out.println("Circumference of the second circle: " +         cir2.findCircumference());
}

 public class Circle{
 //Instance Variables
 private double PI = 3.1459;
 private double radius;
 //Methods
 public Circle ( ) { }

 //get method (Accessor Methods )
 public double getRadius ( ) {
 return radius;
  }
 //set method (Mutator Methods)
 public void setRadius (double r) {
 radius=r;
 }
 public double findArea ( ) {
 return PI*radius*radius; //area= pi r squared
 }
 public double findCircumference ( ) {
 return 2 * PI * radius;
}
}//end Circle
}
```

If anyone could help me understand what I did wrong it would be greatly appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be a simple bracket error.  And perhaps a misuse of the keyword "public" in the Circle class definition.  Here is the revised code:

```
public class CircleDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Circle cir1, cir2;
        cir1 = new Circle();
        cir2 = new Circle();
        cir1.setRadius(3.0);
        cir2.setRadius(11.01);
        System.out.println("Area of the first circle: " + cir1.findArea());
        System.out.println("Circumference of the first circle: " + cir1.findCircumference());
        System.out.println("Area of the second circle: " + cir2.findArea());
        System.out.println("Circumference of the second circle: " +         cir2.findCircumference());

    } //Added this bracket
}

class Circle { //removed the word "public" I'll this explain below
    //Instance Variables
    private double PI = 3.1459;
    private double radius;
    //Methods
    public Circle () {}

    //get method (Accessor Methods )
    public double getRadius ( ) {
        return radius;
    }
    //set method (Mutator Methods)
    public void setRadius (double r) {
        radius=r;
    }
    public double findArea ( ) {
        return PI*radius*radius; //area= pi r squared
    }
        public double findCircumference ( ) {
        return 2 * PI * radius;
    }
} //Removed an extra bracket here
```

Some incorrect brackets were causing the error.  Also, if the Circle class is defined in the same file as the CircleDemo class, then the Circle class must **not** be defined as "public", as this causes an error.  If the Circle class is defined in it's own file, then it can be "public".  I tested this to ensure it works.